# $\mathbb Z^n\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb C^*=(\mathbb C^*)^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In a course on toric geometry I saw the following isomorphism:

$$\mathbb Z^n\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb C^*\cong(\mathbb C^*)^n.$$

Is there a simple and convincing way to explain it? In particular, how is this tensor product defined? Is $\mathbb C^*$ a module over $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$ --- a handy way to think of Abelian groups is $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. In this way the isomorphism you have is an example of taking an isomorphism $A^n \otimes_A M \cong M^n$ for any $A$-module $M$.

Comment: In particular, if you unfold the definitions, the module over $\mathbb{Z}$ has addition operation $x \oplus y = xy$ and scalar multiplication operation $n \odot x = x^n$.

Comment: Yes, it’s a module over the integers. This is true for any module not just $\mathbb{C}^*$. Try using the distributive property of tensor products.